# Inequality problem

Tags: analysis, inequality

Prove that if 
$$|x-x_0| < \min\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2(|y_0| + 1)}, 1\right)$$ and 
$$|y-y_0| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(|x_0| + 1)},$$ 
then $|xy - x_0y_0| < \epsilon.$

I am doing some problems in Spivak's Calculus on inequalities and came across this problem. Currently I have a sketch of a solution that breaks down the problem into many cases and it is kind of long and messy. I thought maybe someone here could provide a clean and easier solution? If there is a nice solution please tell me a bit behind the thought process (like how you came up with it), instead of giving it as it is.

Comment: I haven't thought through this at all, but maybe one of those tricks like rewriting $xy - x_0 y_0$ as $xy - x_0 y + x_0 y - x_0 y_0$ helps.  Of course, if it does, this doesn't necessarily help understand, since it would just be a little algebraic trick.  Though I guess there's value in learning this trick as a tool.

Comment: @matt: That was my first impression on the problem as well: "hmm maybe some algebraic trick would do the job." but it turned out to be long and messy. I guess the key is which algebraic trick?

Comment: I don't know if this is too obvious, but it seems like a delta-epsilon argument to show that f(x,y)=xy is continuous at (xo,yo). Look at 2 possible cases:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
|xy-x_0y_0| &= |xy-xy_0 + xy_0 - x_0y_0|\\
&= |x(y-y_0) + (x-x_0)y_0|\\
&\leq |x(y-y_0)| + |y_0||x-x_0|\\
&= |(x-x_0)(y-y_0) + x_0(y-y_0)| + |y_0||x-x_0|\\
&\leq |x-x_0||y-y_0| + |x_0||y-y_0| + |y_0||x-x_0|\\
&\leq |y-y_0| + |x_0||y-y_0| + |y_0||x-x_0| \\
&= (1+|x_0|)|y-y_0| + |y_0||x-x_0|\\
&\lt (1+|x_0|)\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}\right) + |y_0|\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)}\right)\\
&= \frac{\epsilon}{2} +\left(\frac{|y_0|}{|y_0|+1}\right)\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)\\
&\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&= \epsilon.
\end{align*}$$
We can do the step in line $6$, because $|x-x_0|\lt 1$; we can do the step in line $8$ because $|x-x_0|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)}$ and $|y-y_0|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}$. We can do the step in line 10 because $\frac{|y_0|}{|y_0|+1}\lt 1$.

Comment: looks right to me, I definitely need more practice on inequalities.

Comment: line 10 held me back, +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is another slightly less familiar trick.
$$xy-x_0y_0=(x-x_0)(y-y_0)+y_0(x-x_0)+x_0(y-y_0)$$

Natural, I think, for this problem, since we have some information about $|x-x_0|$ and $|y-y_0|$ in terms of $y_0$ and $x_0$.

Comment: could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: The "standard" identity works poorly because, for example in the $y(x-x_0)$ part, we don't have easy control over $y$.  In the identity that I mention, we have for example the second term $y_0(x-x_0)$, which by the given information has absolute value less than $\epsilon|y_0|/(2|y_0+1)$, so at least less than $\epsilon/2$, which is more or less what we want. The third term has essentially the same nature, and the first term $(x-x_0)(y-y_0)$ is "very" small.

Comment: Help! I cannot find the edit button to fix the missing $ sign.

Comment: @user6312 I've flagged the comment, so hopefully a mod will come and save it for you :).

Comment: @Glen: Thanks, it is embarrassing but not important. I just wanted to provide additional motivation for the trick.

Comment: @Glen, @user6312: fixed. Thanks, Glen, for flagging this.